# Is there a Tor browser on the iPad with iOS 7?

Tags: ios

I have spend many hours trying to find a browser to browse the internet with Tor on an iPad with iOS 7. I only found one which is "covert browser". But it seems it is not supported by the Tor project. It does not appear that a Vidalia package exists for iPad either.

Is there Tor or Vidalia for an iPad and where can I find it?

Comment: Bit late but I would suggest that no, there is no true for browser for iOS. The reason being that all legitimate browser apps for iOS must be a reskinned version of safari. Even chrome is safari. Proof- JavaScript alert of user agent on your own website.

Comment: Roya
the problem with jail breaking your ipad though is, 1. you cant go get it fixed by legit tech guys if something goes wrong.
and the main reason for not doing it is, 2. you can permanently lock down your device, rendering it useless. not even factory reset will work when this happens. 3. Although highly unlikely as it would be a nightmare for apple to do this... apple could take you to court for infringement of rights if you jailbreak your device. google 'jailbreak my ipad', you will find a lot of pros and cons for doing this. is it worth it just to use tor? you can always anonymise yourse

Comment: 1. You *cannot* anonymise yourself using proxies. 2. It is *not illegal* to jailbreak devices that you own, Apple would not be able to take you to court. 3. This isn't an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Onion Browser](https://mike.tig.as/onionbrowser/). It's worth noting that this isn't an official release from the Tor Project so there's no guarantee of what you're getting. The source code is available so at least you can review that if you're interested.

See [this Tor Stack Exchange question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/233/71) for some discussion.

Comment: NB. [Tor Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tor-browser/id712805884?mt=8) for iOS too, with the same caveats as above.

Comment: I didn't list that since the reviews are bad and I haven't found any source code available for review. It also links to the official Tor Project website when they're unaffiliated, which feels dodgy to me.

Comment: Good points :-)

Comment: [Further issues](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10549) with @JonathanDeamer's recommendation.

Comment: Suggestion as something to look into, not recommendation ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Acually there is, but you need to jailbreak your iOS device then search for for on cydia, and install.

Comment: Your answer is quite short and might not be helpful for all users. Could you expand your answer (maybe insert some helpful links, explain what the user should do, where Cydia lives etc.)?